# Positioning in javascript animation

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-animate, position

Lets say i have two divs in my code:

div1   - position(100,100)

div2   - position(100,200)

I am doing a javascript animation and I am wondering if there is any way to give them the same target position on the screen without giving them two different positions?

Ask if you want more information! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not quiet sure if I understand your question.
Something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/WKXV5amtwrQLefidmuAk?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.movediv').animate({
   top:'400',
   left:'400'
 },5000,function(){
 });
});
```

the CSS:

```
div1{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:red;
 position: absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:100px;
}

.div2{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:200px;
 }
```

and the HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="movediv div1"></div> 
  <div class="movediv div2"></div> 
</body>
```